# Can I Create an OnCompile Event Procedure in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, events, compilation

In an Excel VB Project the *`Workbook_Open() Event`* is useful for Initializing things, but is lost whenever the Project is Reset (for example by a Run Time Error, or by the User selecting Design Mode or using the Reset Button in the VBE)

I'd like to be able to automatically run a Procedure (an ***`OnCompile() Event`*** Procedure) whenever the Project is successfully (re-) Compiled

Is this possible please?

Comment: What things do you need to Initializing?
If you need to initialize variables, then an alternative way is to store variables inside cells, you can also create a sheet for variables and make the sheet hidden.

Comment: You would need code that hooks up very, very deep into the VBIDE. [Rubberduck](https://rubberduckvba.com) does hook very, very deep into the VBIDE and only manages to trigger compilation (and know whether it compiled or not). There is no event anywhere for this, so the answer would be "nope, sorry".

Answer (score 1):

The answer to *Is there an OnCompile() Event* is No.

An alternative is to create a user defined class to hold the initialised data.

In the Class Initialise event, gather the required data, similar to what you do in the `Workbook_Open()` event.  Provide properties and methods to access the data.

Declare an instance of it at a globally accessible location.

```
Dim MyInitialsedData As MyInitialsedDataClass
```

Everywhere you access the data use

```
If MyInitialsedData Is Nothing Then
    Set MyInitialsedData = New MyInitialsedDataClass
End If
```

Then access the data with properties and Methods, eg `MyInitialsedData.SomeValue`

Comment: Thanks Chris, but the requirement was for the Initialize Procedure to run Automatically after a Compile ie as an Event. Mathieu Guindon's comment above looks like it may be capable, but I'd really prefer a solution that's Native to VBA is it's possible

Comment: Both my answer and Mathieu's comment say that what you are asking for is not possible.   My answer suggests an alternative that reloads the Initialise data only if required (incluing after a compile) when it's called.  This gives you the functionality you're asking for